# How can I filter a VueJS loop by using checkboxes to show different results?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having trouble with applying filters whilst using checkboxes to a list of results and need some help.

Currently, only the 'All' option seems to apply any filtering logic.

My HTML containing my filters and loop is as follows:

```
<div class="container" id="clubs">
    <div class="filter">
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="All" /> All</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="Parking" /> Parking</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="Toilets" /> Toilets</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="Floodlights" /> Floodlights</label>
    </div>

    <ul class="clubs-list">
        <li v-for="club in filteredClubs">{{ club.clubName }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, the code inside my VueJS app is as below:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el:  "#clubs",
    data: {
        clubs: [
            { clubName: "Club One", clubParking: true, clubToilets: false, clubFloodlights: true },
            { clubName: "Club Two", clubParking: true, clubToilets: false, clubFloodlights: false },
            { clubName: "Club Three", clubParking: false, clubToilets: true, clubFloodlights: true },
        ],
        selectedCategory: "All"
    },
    computed: {
        filteredClubs: function() {
            var vm = this;
            var category = vm.selectedCategory;

            if(category === "All") {
                return vm.clubs;
            } else {
                return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
                    return club.clubParking === category;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help welcome as I have been stuck for hours.

Comment: If you want to support multiple categories, `selectedCategory` needs to be an array: [read the docs on how to use it properly](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox). Also, that means that the `selectedCategory` will be an array of strings, so you can't compare booleans against it. Moreover... you have **multiple** `returns` in your `else` statement. That's not going to work.

Comment: I think this may help me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkymKuIkajE

Comment: Also, your data structure is weird. I would say that `clubParking`, `clubToilets` and etc should be stored under a separate key for easy filtering, e.g. `{ clubName: "Club one", facilities: { parking: true, toilets: false, floodLights: true }}`. Do you have the choice to change the structure of the data?

Comment: I can change the data structure. I did think the way it was is correct based on https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: The data structure is fine.  I would remove the prefix `club` though. It is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your filter to check the category, then filter on the field.

```
return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
  switch(category){
     case 'Toilets':
      return club.clubToilets;
     case 'Parking':
      return club.clubParking;
     // etc...
  }
});
```

You can refactor this a bit by setting a field name.

```
return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
  let fname;
  switch(category){
     case 'Toilets':
      fname ='clubToilets';
     case 'Parking':
      fname = 'clubParking';
     // etc...
  }
  return club[fname]
});
```

You can also simply have the value of the select be your field name and use it directly.  This may restrict you from additional logic however.

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="clubParking" /> Parking</label>
```

```js
return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
  return club[category];
}
```

The bottom line is the category must be mapped to a field name in your object.

## For multiple items:

```
// Map the field names depending on your checkbox values. `selectedCategory` should be an array.

const selectedFieldNames =  selectedCategory.map(category=>{
      switch(category){
         case 'Toilets':
          return 'clubToilets';
         case 'Parking':
          return 'clubParking';
         // etc...
      }
})

// selectedFieldNames now contains the names of your object fields

// This will now return all items that have all those fields set to 'true'
return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
  return selectedFieldNames.every(fname=>club[fname])
}
```

## Working Example Based On Your Posted Code.

Note: This really could use some cleaning up, but I left it in a format that you can compare your work and ours.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
 el: "#clubs",
 data: {
  clubs: [
   {
    clubName: "Club One",
    clubParking: true,
    clubToilets: false,
    clubFloodlights: true
   },
   {
    clubName: "Club Two",
    clubParking: true,
    clubToilets: false,
    clubFloodlights: false
   },
   {
    clubName: "Club Three",
    clubParking: false,
    clubToilets: true,
    clubFloodlights: true
   }
  ],
  selectedCategory: []
 },
 computed: {
  filteredClubs: function() {
   var vm = this;
   var categories = vm.selectedCategory;
      
   if (categories.includes("All")) {
    return vm.clubs;
   } else {
    const selectedFieldNames = categories.map(category => {
     switch (category) {
      case "ClubToilets":
       return "clubToilets";
      case "ClubParking":
       return "clubParking";
      case "ClubFloodlights":
       return "clubFloodlights";
     }
    });

    return vm.clubs.filter(function(club) {
     return selectedFieldNames.every(fname=>club[fname])
    })   
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="clubs">
 <div class="filter">
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="All" /> All</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="ClubParking" /> Parking</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="ClubToilets" /> Toilets</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedCategory" value="ClubFloodlights" /> Floodlights</label>
 </div>
 
 <ul class="clubs-list">
  <li v-for="club in filteredClubs">{{ club.clubName }}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution definitely works when I change the checkboxes to radio buttons. However, I do need the ability for the user to select multiple options.

Comment: The same applies to checkboxes/multiselect, but you would put the field names in an array and then do a [].some or [].every depending on your logic requirements ( and/or).

Comment: @Al-76 I added a sample on how to test multiple fields.

Comment: Thanks guy for your help. Sorry I'm rather lost with it all. I do appreciate your help though and patient.

Comment: That last example is your ticket!

Comment: @Al-76 I posted a working example.  Make sure your data is an array for the check boxes...